# Drupal 7 : Filter Content based on Content types

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How do i create a dropdown box with all the content types which filter out the data on page.tpl.php. Even if I create a dropdown box myself filled with the content types , how would I able to write a functionality to filter nodes based on selected content type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) you can use parameters passed via the url to filter data. You can generate a drop-down box using forEach in PHP using data fetched by using [hooks](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--docs--docs.php/group/views_hooks/6). After that you should be able to pass the parameters to a views page and get what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you I just did it with frontpage view.

Answer (score 0):

1. contextual filter
2. When the filter value is NOT available
3. Provide default value
4. PHP Code
5. if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
     return $node->type;
   }
6. apply
7. rejoice